# why dict(dict) get the same dict?

Tags: python

It might sounds stupid. When I override dict in python like:

```
class idict(dict):
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._store = dict(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I use

```
a = {1:2, 2:3}
b=idict(a)
print b._store == a
```

gives `True`

I don't know why `dict(dict)` get the same dict. Does dict in python have any method handle this? I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right way.

Another question further of this one:

If I know I will get a parent class instance (like dict), I want to add/change method in this instance. I usually create child class from parent class and get child class instance. This seems memory-inefficient, as parent instance is already there.

One way after my search is adding/changing a method in the parent class directly (e.g. `parent_class.method = new_method`), and then get the instance of parent class. I'm not sure if this is right way in terms of OOP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not getting the same `dict`. It's making a shallow copy of the original `dict`, and `==` compares by value, not by identity, so because it has all the same keys and values, it's equal, even though it's not the *same* `dict`.

If you tested `print b._store is a`, you'd get `False`, because `is` tests object identity.

As for your other question, I'm not 100% sure what you're going for there, but I think you're objecting to the fact that you aren't benefiting from inheriting from `dict`, since you still have an attribute storing all your values. That's only because you're not doing inheritance correctly here. You have to delegate up to the parent class's methods, rather than making your own `_store` attribute, and you'll reuse the storage of the parent. So for example, a correct `__init__` here would be:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # On Py2 super(idict, self) needed instead of super()
```

Now you don't have `_store` at all, you're initializing the parent class storage  by passing the work up the chain.

Side-note: Technically, the correct `__init__` would be:

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    if not args:
        raise TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object "
                        "needs an argument")
    self = args[0]
    if len(args) > 2:
        raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))

    super(idict, self).__init__(*args[1:], **kwargs)
```

This is a special case that only applies to methods intended to accept arbitrary keywords, where you need to detect and properly respond to the possibility that a caller might pass `self=someval` without raising exception (e.g. in the case of `dict`, `dict(self="abc")` is legal). Python `dict` subclasses like `collections.Counter` use this technique.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying all my questions and some tips. I know super() is used like delegate to parent class's method from Python's docs, but it feels odd that I don't need a variable to point to the parent instance. If I add a new method `m` in the child class `c`, does `super()` also let me access the instance created from `super().__init__()` after I initialize an instance of `c`?

Comment: @Finix: You don't need a variable to point to the parent instance because `self` _is_ the variable that points to a parent instance (which is also the child instance; that's what subclassing means). `super` is just a convenience function that lets you call the parent methods even when you've overridden them. If your child method `m` needs to do things with the parent methods, just call them. If you've overridden them, and `m` should call the parent method directly, you can use `super`; it's just a wrapper to bypass the current class's methods, so it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. I forget every instance uses `self` to bound itself to its class methods. In this case, simply use `super` to call parent class method is fine now.